# How to call stored procedure from C#, and get the returned value?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure in SQL Server, and loaded into `a.dbml`, a database file in my Visual Studio project. The procedure is called `storedprocedure1(System.String name, System.Int32 code)`.

Now in my MVC controller (let's call it `FooController`), I am writing a method to get the result from the stored procedure. How do I do that?

Database class:

```
namespace App.Repo.App_Data{
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name="Application")]
    public partial class APPDatacontext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext{ /* ... */}
}
```

Controller class

```
namespace App.Controllers{
    public class FooController : Controller{
        private string getResult(string name, int code){
            // call and get result from storedprocedure1
        }
    }
}
```

SQL Server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE storedprocedure1 (
    @name varchar(10),
    @code int
    @result varchar(50) OUTPUT
)
AS

    SELECT --blah blah blah

GO
```

Comment: its a dataset returned from the stored procedure, right? a table of rows..?

Comment: So now you have edited your query. What do you want in the @result variable??? You need to specify what value will be returned somewhere in your procedure. Also, don't forget to specify the parameter direction when you call your procedure. The default direction is INPUT and will not be populated unless you specify it as OUTPUT.

Comment: `@result` will be `SELECTed` in the query. The value selected is unique (`top 1`). Other 2 parameters are INPUT parameters.

Comment: OK. So then you are good to go now?

Comment: I was asking how to get `@result` from the controller in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use RETURN to return values from a procedure. The RETURN value is an integer and is designed to provide a value indicating the status of the execution. If you want values back from your procedures you should use OUTPUT variables.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108%28v=sql.110%29.aspx